# Bulk Rename Utility

Tags: regex, sed, rename, batch-rename, bulk

I have been using [Bulk Rename utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) and I have been having some issues. I have some files named things like `664722.pdf`,`664762.pdf`, and `664722-1.pdf` that I need to rename. The problem is I have to rename about 50 of these at a time.

So, I am converting from the top to the bottom row.

```
664722.pdf              664762.pdf              664722-1.pdf
```

```
664722-LabelProof.pdf   664762-LabelProof.pdf   664722-1-LabelProof.pdf
```

So, right now I have to do `([0-9]{6})(-[0-9])?` and name the files to `\1\2-LabelProof` and THEN drop back to `([0-9]{6})(-[0-9])?` and name the files to `\1-LabelProof` I am on windows.

Is anyone able to come up with a Regex that can match both 664722 AND 664722-1 at the same time and I can still call something to convert both jobs with and without subs to have -LabelProof at the end.

I thought about matching something like .pdf to replace it with -LabelProof.pdf, but it wont just be these PDFs. These are just the new ones and I have to leave all of the other ones alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `([0-9]{6}(-[0-9])?)\.pdf` and replace with `\1-LabelProof.pdf`. This will make it so that `\1` includes everything before `.pdf`, on both files with and without dash and a number.

This matches a six numbers in a row, then matches a dash and a number in the form `-3` either 0 or 1 times. Basically six numbers and then a `- number` if it is there.

Comment: No, you understand me wrong. Then I would also be renaming `00258252.pdf` to `00258252-LabelProof.pdf` which would be bad. (this is the standard proof sheet for that cust number.) or in fact would also rename `ShippingDetails1.pdf` or `data_09202013.pdf` or anything that ends in [number].pdf would be renamed.

Comment: @user255763 I'm sorry if I didn't understand. What is wrong with your original `([0-9]{6})(-[0-9])?`, what is it matching that it shouldn't, or what is it failing to match?

Comment: on the ones like `665445.pdf` it is matching as `665445\2.pdf`

Comment: @user255763 Ah, now I understand. See my updated answer.

Comment: Oh? A sub-pattern? interesting. I didn't know that you can do that. Works perfectly

Comment: I added the bad way I had thought of to work right before your answer. yours is still clearly better though, so it's the best answer. I'd upvote, but I can't :(

Answer (score 1):

`([0-9,\-]{6,8}).pdf` is what I ended up using. It matches a number digit or a - between 6 and 8 times and then the extension to prevent ones that have already been renamed like `665485-LabelProof.pdf` from being renamed again and adding a dash. Not the best but it works.

The bad part about this one is that it would also match filenames like `--1-45-8.pdf` and, without the .pdf at the end like i mentioned, it would also replace

```
664722-1-LabelProof.pdf
664722-1-LabelProof-LabelProof.pdf
```